# Значение value у option переносить в input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Мне надо реализовать, чтобы при замене option изменялось значение value и у input. Прикладываю, как я пытался реализовать.
html

```
    <select name="webmenu_2" id="webmenu_2" class="webmenu_2"> 
        <option value="+ 12" data-image="img/rus_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 13" data-image="img/eng_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 14" data-image="img/ger_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 152" data-image="img/esp_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 162" data-image="img/port_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 172" data-image="img/fra_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 182" data-image="img/ita_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 192" data-image="img/Pol_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 112" data-image="img/iz_2.png" ></option> 
        <option value="+ 1672" data-image="img/chi_2.png"></option> 
        <option value="+ 112" data-image="img/Tur_2.png"></option> 
    </select> 
    <input type="text" class="callyouback__number_ph">
```

и js

```
if ($('.callyouback__number_ph').val() != $('.webmenu_2').val()) {
    $('.callyouback__number_ph').attr('value', $('.webmenu_2').val()); 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#webmenu_2").on("change", function() {
  if ($('.callyouback__number_ph').val() != $('.webmenu_2').val()) {
      $('.callyouback__number_ph').attr('value', $('.webmenu_2').val()); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Минус в карму - это сильно. Но не конструктивно и по детски. Есть претензии, пишем в комментарии.

Comment: Привет. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Сейчас ещё не могу пометить как правильный ответ, надо подождать 6 минут

Comment: @ИванТрушко Пожалуйста! Главное не забудь. ;)

Comment: Минус не я влепил, но может это не понравилось минусодателю: `.attr('value'`

Comment: @РустамГимранов да поди гадай, что не понравилось. Ладно, это не важно. Главное что вопрос решён! :)

Comment: А в общем не понятно, зачем проверять, когда можно сразу: `$('.callyouback__number_ph').val($(this).val());`

Comment: минусы и плюсы оценивают качество ответа, а не то решен он или нет. если для вас главное решить, а не решить оптимально и грамотно, то минусы и будут.

Comment: в данном случае, код будет проще если `on-change` -> `change`, `(.webmenu)` внутри на `$(this)`, а `attr('value')` на `val()`, и убрать этот `if`.

Comment: @teran Ничего не имею против красивого аккуратного кода! Сам стараюсь такой писать. Вот только вопрос был в том, что у человека не получалось вывести данные из select в input. И он не просил устраивать код ревью. Докопаться можно до чего угодно и оптимизировать до бесконечности, а ещё можно сделать uglyfy и minify, чтобы меньше весло. Вот только вы усложняете простую задачу. А пользы от этого не то что бы очень много. Правильно говорят, задал вопрос на английском форуме - получил ответ, задал вопрос на русском форуме - узнал почему твой код говно.

Comment: одно другому не мешает.

Comment: @teran В краткосрочной перспективе - может быть. А вот в долгосрочной, ещё как мешает. Перфекционизм должен быть управляем! Когда заказчик просит решить проблему, а программист вместо решения начинает наводить в его коде дзен & красоту, тратя лишнее время - это не круто! Заказчику от этого не тепло не холодно. Заказчикам вообще часто плевать, как код выглядит изнутри. Проблема либо решена, либо нет. 3-его не дано. И приоритет всегда будет отдаватья простым и понятным решениям, пусть даже топорным и костыльным. Но я как разработчик - разработчика вас понимаю!)

Comment: вопрос в том, что мы тут не реальный проект и его баги обсуждаем, а учебную задачу. Человек учится, и если в своем коде помимо ошибки он сделал еще 10 косяков, то в целях обучения ему следует об этом написать. Адекватный заказчик впрочем тоже должен понимать, что сопровождение плохого кода требует больших затрат, умственных, временных, финансовых.

Comment: @teran Адекватный заказчик, я вас умоляю! Где вы таких видели!? )))) Но это всё лирика. Если по сабжу, то мы опять приходим к "ТЗ". Задача стояла так: "Мне надо реализовать, чтобы при замене option изменялось значение value и у input." Всё. Никаких рассуждений. Никаких просьб о критике. Всё то, что мы с вами тут обсуждаем, это наши домыслы. Что возмо-о-ожно автор учится и возмо-о-ожно ему пригодился бы совет по оптимизации. А возможно и нет. Я думаю резонно сделать так. Чтобы не разводить полемику. Оформите ответ с вашими рекомендация для автора. Всё остальное будет на его совести! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = $('.callyouback__number_ph'),
    select = $('.webmenu_2');

changeValue()

select.on('change', function () {
  changeValue($(this).val())
})


function changeValue(value) {
  if(value != undefined) {
    if (input.val() != value) {
      input.val(value); 
    } 
  } else {
    input.val(select.val());
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0fowa9tv